# select custom post type on regular post

Tags: custom-post-types

I have created a custom post type about broker profile, which contains broker information (name, image , link etc)

Now what i want is, while creating new post , I want a section where I can choose brokers profile. 
And display broker information on post details.

Any idea how can i do that?

Comment: you can add a box on the edit page with this function : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/

Answer (score 0):

you can use CMB2 you can do this easy https://github.com/CMB2/cmb2-attached-posts  take a look at this GitHub to show you how.